# recode NA in factors

Tags: r

I've got a data frame containing groups of sample points:

```
samplePoint<-c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
category<-c("a", "a", "a", NA, "b", "b", NA, "b", NA, "a", "a", "a")
values<-c(0.51, 0.21, 0.31, 0.22, 0.61, 0.71, 0.52, 0.32, 0.23, 0.1, 0.24, 0.33)
dat<-data.frame(samplePoint, category, values)
```

I need to recode the NAs in dat$category for something later on in the process. Each sample point will only have one category: 1 should all be "a", 2 = "b" and 3 ="a".

I've tried aggregate using an ifelse function, intending to recode using a match or lookup type function:

```
codeList<-aggregate(
dat$category, by=list(dat$samplePoint),
FUN=function(x){ifelse(length(which(x=="a")) > length(which(x=="b")), "a", "b")}
)
```

Question 1 is, how do I tackle the matching?
Question 2 is have I totally overcomplicated the whole thing?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: you don't, because,
Q2: yes, massively.

What you can do is use call `factor` on your sample points appropriately transformed and with the required labels.

```
category <- factor((as.numeric(samplePoint)+1)%%2,labels=letters[1:2])
category
 [1] a a a a b b b b a a a a
Levels: a b
```

The transformation uses the modulus operator (%%) to convert the sample points to binary output, but the points are shifted to make the points 1 and 3 correspond to the label `"a"`. Any further points would be coded in the same way, ie 4: "b", 5: "a".

**Update**

After getting the clarification in the comment, I think this might help:

```
(catTable <- aggregate(category,list(samplePoint=samplePoint),function(x) unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
  samplePoint x
1           1 a
2           2 b
3           3 a
```

This gives you a data.frame which you can `merge` with your original data to get what you want.

```
merge(dat,catTable,all.x=T)
   samplePoint category values x
1            1        a   0.51 a
2            1        a   0.21 a
3            1        a   0.31 a
4            1     <NA>   0.22 a
5            2        b   0.61 b
6            2        b   0.71 b
7            2     <NA>   0.52 b
8            2        b   0.32 b
9            3     <NA>   0.23 a
10           3        a   0.10 a
11           3        a   0.24 a
12           3        a   0.33 a
```

Comment: James, that's awesome - I'd not seen modulo used to that effect before. Sadly, I can't be sure dat$category follows that pattern throughout my data set. Sample point 4 could be a's

Comment: Yes - you've done it - thank you so much, that's been driving me crazy. I made a small change: dat$category<-merge(dat, catTable, all.x=T)$x) to replace the original.